# Place marker after Autocomplete - Google Places Android API

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I am using Google Places Autocomplete API to get **Autocomplete** Prediction results (as a list from an EditText):

```
PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
           Places.GeoDataApi
           .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
           mBounds, mPlaceFilter);

AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
```

**Problem:**

My goal is to add a marker from the user-chosen Autocomplete result.

For that, you need latitude and longitude.
Autocomplete API returns a list of AutocompletePrediction objects. **But, AutocompletePrediction doesn't have a LatLng field.**

Instead, it gives you a PlaceId - from this I get a Place object (LatLng) by making another network call: Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById.

`Getting Place object from PlaceId is another network call and slows down the UI.  Can I avoid this somehow?`

Comment: I think you have to do another network request to get a place coordinates from a place ID. Even you use the [Autocomplete web service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete?hl=en), you still have to get a list of place IDs first, then do a place detail request to get place coordinates with a place ID. You can see [this example](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/) about how it has to do another request for place coordiantes, even thought its not using `AutocompletePrediction` but web service.